# Is it possible to find a torsion-free space with non-trivial $\operatorname{Sq}^{2^n}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, cohomology-operations

> Is it possible to find a torsion-free space with non-trivial $\operatorname{Sq}^{2^n}$ ?

Torsion-free means integral cohomology is torsion-free. When $n \leq 3$, such spaces are projective space $\mathbb{CP}^n$, $\mathbb{HP}^n$ and the Cayley plane. $\operatorname{Sq}^{2^n}$ takes the generator of degree $2^n$ to the generator of degree $2^{n+1}$. So what is such a space for $n > 3$? That is, can we find a torsion-free space $X$ such that the indecomposable element $\operatorname{Sq}^{2^n}$ acts non-trivially on mod 2 cohomology of $X$?

Comment: Typo: change "$n \leq 4$" to "$n \leq 3$". The Cayley plane has nonzero cohomology in dimensions 8 and 16, connected by $\textrm{Sq}^8$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\textrm{Sq}^{2^n}$ acts non-trivially on the mod 2 cohomology of $\mathbb{C}P^{m}$ if $m \geq 2^{n}$: it takes the nonzero element in dimension $2^n$ to the nonzero element in dimension $2^{n+1}$. This is true because for any cohomology class $x$ in dimension $d$, $\textrm{Sq}^d x = x^2$.

If you want a space which has nonzero cohomology only in dimensions $2^n$ and $2^{n+1}$, connected by $\textrm{Sq}^{2^n}$, this is impossible for $n\geq 4$ by [Adams' Hopf invariant one theorem](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/adams1.pdf)

Comment: What you said is $(Sq^{2})^{n}$,not $Sq^{2^{n}}

Comment: @Brooks I've added a sentence to the first paragraph explaining my reasoning. Also note that $(Sq^2)^4=0$.

Comment: oh,I make clear.Thank you